# Анимация: проход по очереди и до бесконечности

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть такая картинка

[image]

Так вот скажите, как загрузить в PictureBox1 только одного человечка, и потом сделать его анимацию, чтобы, к примеру, по очереди и до бесконечности проходил первый ряд?

Вот как выглядит форма

[image: form]

Вот как она должна работать с картинкой

[image: form]

Comment: двигайте картинку на нужные координаты...

Comment: Да а можете показать это в небольшом примере?

Comment: Не могу, ибо я не знаю C#

Answer (score 1):

Нужно взять рисунок, который вы хотите перемещать по PictureBox, и по таймеру его прорисовывать, перемещая по координатам (координаты пересчитывать в обработчике таймера)

```
public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bitmap = new Bitmap(picturebox.Width, picturebox.Height);
    picturebox.Image = bitmap;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(performTick);
    timer.Interval = 10;

    timer.Start();
}

void performTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Здесь перерисовать bitmap
    picturebox.Image = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Картинка появляется на милисекунду и исчезает и больше не появляется.

Comment: Это не более, чем заготовка, показывающая принцип перерисовки по таймеру. Ее надо доделывать: менять время, менять координаты и т.п.

Comment: Обновил первый пост...